# Neighbor switch's port doesn't change to access mode

Tags: trunk

When Switch A's port is configured to access mode from trunk mode, Switch B's port stays in trunk mode.

Switch A is DTP disabled (#switchport nonegotiate). Switch B has default configuration which is dynamic auto and DTP enabled.

Is this normal?

Comment: a) what are the types and IOS versions of each switch? b) include the configuration of the ports (`show run int xxx`) c) are you using VTP? As a general rule, *never* trust DTP.

Comment: DTP is almost as bad as VTP. It's worth trying it out in a lab, but disabling it will save you in the future. Plus not all Cisco gear supports it (NX-OS...) and it is a security hole (user can DTP-negotiate an edge port to a trunk, allow access to all vlans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTP by default has 300 seconds of Dynamic Trunk timeout. So, Switch B will change its port operational mode to "static access" if it will have not received any DTP advertisement to trunk in the next 300 seconds [after it changes the port operational mode to "static access" or since the receive of the DTP advertisement to trunk].

I tested and the Switch B's port operational mode was changed from "trunk" to "static access" after 300 seconds.

Note: The statement in [ ] is not confirmed. It is supposed to be either one.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on when the commands were typed in, this sounds like the expected behaviour.  If `Switch A` were plugged into `Switch B`, and `Switch A` moved to the trunk state, then DTP on `Switch B` would have negotiated trunk mode.

This is how DTP *normally* negotiates the interface mode:

```
Table 3-8 DTP Negotiated Interface Modes

                Dynamic       Dynamic     Trunk        Access
                Auto          Desirable

Dynamic Auto    Access        Trunk       Trunk        Access <-- Should be here


Dynamic         Trunk         Trunk       Trunk        Access
Desirable

Trunk           Trunk         Trunk       Trunk        Limited 
                                                   connectivity

Access          Access        Access      Limited      Access
                                      connectivity
```

<sup>[Cisco Press, Cisco Networking Academy's Introduction to VLANs, Table 3-8](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2181837&seqNum=8)</sup>

However, if you disabled DTP on `Switch A`, then `Switch B` would have no further knowledge of any changes in interface changes on `Switch A`.  So moving `Switch A` to access will not be conveyed to `Switch B`, as it would have normally expected.

If you reset the connection between them, `Switch B` would have never changed it's mode to trunk and remain in access mode.  Then you'd be having the total opposite problem (`Switch B` not turning into a trunk).

Comment: It'll change after timeout of Dynamic Trunk timeout time.